# how to split the values into different arrays according to date

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am having a problem i  displaying price of rooms of different dates in different array.Waht i am getting is

```
Array[1]
0
:
Object
checkIn
:
"2016-04-19 00:00:00"
extraAdultCharge
:
"[{"2016-04-19":"400.000"},{"2016-04-20":"400.000"}]"
extraChildCharge
:
"[{"2016-04-19":"400.000"},{"2016-04-20":"400.000"}]"
netRateDouble
:
"[{"2016-04-19":"1600.000"},{"2016-04-20":"1600.000"}]"
netRateSingle
:
"[{"2016-04-19":"1300.000"},{"2016-04-20":"1300.000"}]"
__proto__
:
```

What should i do to get it in a format like in 
array1 comes the price of a date and in array2 comes the price of different date.

Comment: Looping through the array and store the values according to dates would help. Have you tried anything?

Comment: the above code is unclear. It would be ideal if you could reformat and show the input data and the expected result

Comment: no can you show me how to add a foreach loop.